# DBeaver: ошибка Connection refused

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mariadb, connection, dbeaver

Пожалуйста, помогите начать пользоваться DBeaver!

Создаю connection к базе данных (MySQL, MariaDB), придумываю пароль. При нажатии на кнопку test connection программа предлагает установить драйвер. Драйвер устанавливается, после чего вылезает ошибка соединения. Текст разным видам БД разный, но суть одна.

Например для mariaDB:

> Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master)
> : Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection
> refused (Connection refused)   Socket fail to connect to
> host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection
> refused (Connection refused)
> Connection refused (Connection refused)
> Connection refused (Connection refused)

Для MySQL:

> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> Connection refused (Connection refused)   Connection refused
> (Connection refused)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А база точно поднята? Она на том же компе (сервере), что и программа?

Comment: @lezhni какая база?

Comment: База данных, к которой хотите подключиться)

Comment: @lezhni как ее создать?

Comment: DBeaver это клиент mysql, то есть у вас должен быть запущен сервер mysql, с которым потом можно будет работать. В зависимости от системы, есть куча вариантов, как запустить сервер mysql